# Scala Play Framework Database interoperability

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm

Could someone explain to me or give me a link where I can read about the Database interoperability showed here? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.0/ScalaAnorm

I want to understand how implicit conversion works and what means this below:

```
  implicit def timeStampToDateTime: Column[Timestamp] = Column.nonNull { (value, meta) =>

    val MetaDataItem(qualified, nullable, clazz) = meta

    value match {
        case ts: java.sql.Timestamp => Right(ts)
        case _ => Left(TypeDoesNotMatch("Cannot convert " + value + ":" + value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass) )
    }
}
```

I didn't find documentation searching on google, perhaps here someone can explain me what the "Right" and "Left" means.

Comment: The question is too fuzzy. `Right` & `Left` are not specific to Anorm, but only case classes of Scala `Either`. A Scala tutorial would be nice to read. Moreover you look at doc of an old Play version (latest been 2.3.7).

Comment: Thanks, now I know that Right and Left has nothing with anorm, but it is a way to return some custom error message.

Comment: You need to look at a Scala tutorial or book to understand common types such as `Either`